# Как в form подставить нужное значение для model django

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, в которой, при записи модели, надо подставлять нужную категорию. как это сделать?

Есть форма, которая имеет только поле `device`

**forms.py**

```
class FastForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device']
```

Есть модель, в которой есть `category`, которая имеет `ForeignKey` и две записи с `pk=1` и `pk=2`

**models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
```

**вопрос:**
как в `forms.py` в классе `FastForm`, указывать, что надо именно записывать в поле `category` значение `pk=2`, а не `default`?

Comment: поменяйте `default` на 2)) а если серьёзно то передавайте `id` категории в форме, добавив туда соответствующее поле

Comment: в форму не надо, всегда значение id=2, проще в forms указывать, чем в шаблоне. вопрос как

Comment: решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266326/295536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> вопрос: как в forms.py в классе FastForm, указывать, что надо именно записывать в поле category значение pk=2, а не default?

Добавьте в форму поле `category`.

```
fields = ['device', 'category']
```

Если хотите, чтобы в поле выводился `id`, в модели перегрузите метод `__str__`.

Comment: но мне надо чтобы форма  в html {{ forme.as_p }}, выводилась без этого поля, но само поле можно было переопределить в view или form

Comment: то есть пользователь не должен иметь возможность вводить это поле

Comment: тогда переопределяйте поле во view, в чем проблема?)

Comment: то есть я должен сам указывать внутри view что там должно быть

Comment: исходя из того, что вы хотите - да)

Comment: в таком случае - в форме замените ```ModelForm``` на ```Form```, а в view добавьте ```form.category = 1```, иначе оно не будет переопределяться. Ставьте галку. И другие вопросы просмотрите свои - вы не ответили там.

Comment: решение проще оказалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266326/295536

Comment: Я просто перестану отвечать на ваши вопросы. Вы создаёте дубли. Не читаете ответы.

Comment: я прочитал ваши ответы. ваш ответ был не правильный и ввел меня в заблуждение. решение было проще и если бы я последовал вашему примеру, пришлось бы бессмысленно переписывать код. ModelForm принимает для модели переменные, но не принимает для foreignKey, поэтому приходится обращаться по _id, а не по названию перменной в модели

Comment: и я не создаю дубли, я создаю новый вопрос, переформулированный