# Изменить значение по умолчанию для модели в форме django forms models

Tags: python, django

как в классе `forms.py` перезаписать значение по умолчанию поля модели `category`, не добавляя его в форму html?

**forms.py**

```
class FastForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device']
```

**models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
```

то есть в базе должна появится запись со значением поля `category`, которое я укажу в классе формы `FastForm`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в form подставить нужное значение для model django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265448/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-form-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-model-django)

Comment: да, на тот не дали ответа, я переформулировал вопрос в другом контексте

Comment: решение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266326/295536