# ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Orders.category" must be a "Category" instance. django

Tags: python, django

Надо сохранить form, но так же поменять значение которое есть в model по умолчанию

**forms**

```
class SimpleOrderAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device']
        widgets = {
            'device': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete':'off'}),
        }
```

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', default=1, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория', related_name='get_category')

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
```

**views**

```
   formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST)
   if formOne.is_valid():
        form_update = formOne.save(commit=False)
        form_update.category = 2            
        form_update.save()            
        return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(formOne **kwargs)
```

почему не записывается `SimpleOrderAddForm`, не перезаписывается `form_update.category = 2`, и выдает ошибку `ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "Orders.category" must be a "Category" instance.`

Answer (score 1):

Обращаться надо к полю c id записью

**form_update.category_id = 2**

Answer (score 1):

поле Orders.category ожидает инстанс(объект) модели Category. Можно передать его так:

```
 if formOne.is_valid():
        form_update = formOne.save(commit=False)

        category = Category.objects.get(id=2)
        form_update.category = category

        form_update.save()            
        return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
```

Хотя на мой взгляд хардкодить *id* категории не очень корректно, ведь когда Вы создадите несколько категорий, а потом какие-то удалите, угадать какой теперь *id* получила категория от *app_name_model_name_id_seq* будет невозможно(придется лезть в базу). Так что считаю, что лучше присваивать инстанс *Category* в данном случае по полю *title*, то есть так:

```
category = Category.objects.get(title='title созданной категории')
```